# Google Sites: Insert date published for pages within a site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm very new to Google Sites and I'm wondering how to insert date published and last updated for pages within a site (not a using a blog template).

It looks like I could use Apps Scripts along with

```
utilities.formatDate(SitesApp.getActivePage().getDatePublished(), "GMT", "d-MMM-yyyy")
```

and

```
ContentService
```

but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to display last update and published date on your Google Site. You can use this code to create an Apps Script Gadget which then you can embed in Google Site.

```
function doGet(e){
  var app= UiApp.createApplication();
  var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
  app.add(app.createHTML('Last updated: ' + page.getLastUpdated()));
  app.add(app.createHTML('Published: '+page.getDatePublished()));
  return app;
}
```

You can see a demo [here](https://sites.google.com/site/appsdatepicker/last-updated-published-test)

For more information on Gadgets in Google Site, visit [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets)